# Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations

Tags: eosjs, signing

I am trying to sign transaction and push manually using eosjs.

```js
  const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([privateKey]);

  const sigResult = await signatureProvider.sign({
    chainId: chainId,
    requiredKeys: [publicKey],
    serializedTransaction,
    abis,
  });
```

I can see it's signed, but when I push the transaction, I get following error.

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3090003,
    "name": "unsatisfied_authorization",
    "what": "Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "transaction declares authority '{\"actor\":\"MYUSER\",\"permission\":\"owner\"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], provided keys ${provided_keys}, and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms",
        "file": "authorization_manager.cpp",
        "line_number": 532,
        "method": "check_authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea what is causing the issue? I am using the correct private & public key for that actor...

Comment: Looks like you have not imported the owner keys for that account.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. It was because of bad chain id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by the question author:
"Never mind, I figured it out. It was because of bad chain id"